# passing params in nested stack navigator react navigation V3 is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have tried passing params to my stackNavigator but still I am getting Undefined for some reason. Here is my code:

**First the stackNav:**

```
const BOOKS_PAGE = createStackNavigator(
    {
        booksPage: {
            screen: Books,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: i18n.t('BOOKS'),
                headerStyle,
                headerTitleStyle,
                headerLeft: currentLanguage === 'en' ? headerLeft : null,
                headerRight: currentLanguage !== 'en' ? headerRight : null,
            }
        }
    },
    {
        headerLayoutPreset: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : 'center'
    }
);
```

**Then I have a drawer nav as the main nav and it contains the above stack nav:**

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        BOOKS: {
            screen: BOOKS_PAGE,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: i18n.t('BOOKS'),
                drawerLabel: i18n.t('BOOKS')
            }
        },

    },
    DrawerConfig
);
```

**and finally this is my navigate action:**

```
 function navigate(routeName, booksObject) {
    navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params: {
                levelName: booksObject.levelName
            },
        })
    );
}
```

I tried using `this.props.navigation.state` and `this.props.navigation.state.params` and `this.props.navigation.getParam('levelName')` but it all came back as undefined.

Any Idea on how am I supposed to tackle this?